# Why did Vyasa advice Ashwatthama to release his Brahmashira in the wombs of Pandava women?

Tags: mahabharata, vyasa

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m10/m10015.htm

> Vyasa said, "Do then this. Do not, however, entertain any other purpose, O sinless one! Throwing this weapon into the wombs of the Pandava women, stop thyself."